# Google Chrome update CSS file

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have `LoginFormStyleSheet.css` which contains

```
.divLoginFormClass{
    position: absolute;
    width: 350px;
    height: 150px;
    margin:auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

i'm changed this class to

```
.divLoginFormClass{
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    margin:auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

But Google Chrome 31.0.1650.63 m get the old version of `LoginFormStyleSheet.css` where `width: 350px`. How to fix this? There is no the same trouble in the `IE9`.

Comment: Sounds like it has been cached in Chrome. Try clearing the cache and refreshing?

Comment: try `Ctrl+F5` to clear the cache..

Comment: @JoshC Is it possible to avoid manually cleaning cashe via client-side/server-side code?

Comment: @St.Antario Don't use the same file name. One possibility is to date-stamp your file names (`loginSyltes12102013.css`), and another is to make it a request to a php file with parameters instead (`css.php?v=147`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean your browser data to see the new CSS taking effect. Alternatively you can also do `Ctrl+F5`